# "Cut the rope" view levels current scores / time

Tags: ios, cut-the-rope

(on iPhone 4, iOS4)

*Cut the rope* is really a great game. I installed both the full version and the Xmas version.

However there are two things pretty annoying

1. Opening the levels page shows first a *cutter* animation taking 3~5 seconds. It really seems to be on purpose (not an animation during a load operation from another *thread* for instance). I know there is nothing we can do about it... just in case the game writers read these forums :-)
2. Beating the previous score of a given level shows an `improved` image. And one may know, this way, that the score was beaten. However there doesn't seem to be any way to see the current score / time for a given level. Any suggestion?

(My question is 2. Thanks)

Comment: There's an Xmas version of Cut the Rope? For the love...

Comment: @VJV Only 25 levels but they are pretty good. And free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just access the level and click menu, the topright of the screen will give you your current score.

Comment: One word: wow!!

Answer (score 2):

As said, seeing the current score/time is not possible. For this and the first point, you should head to the game's publisher website [contact page](http://www.chillingo.com/contact.htm) and send a message. Who knows? :)

Answer (score 0):

Ask the developer? Not exactly sure what you're expecting individuals on StackExchange to come up with that only the developer can implement (view previous/current level high score) if the feature doesn't currently exist.

Comment: @AM You see, check the answer from *mistry* ... some people are more observant than us ;-)